# Why can't my POSTGRESQL trigger function find my column when using the NEW parameter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a function that updates a field to 0 when the field of another column is a certain value. Here is my table

```
flightbooking
---------------------------------
| bookingID | numseats | status |
---------------------------------
| 1         | 5        | R      |
| 2         | 8        | R      |
---------------------------------
```

So when status is changed from 'R' to 'C' I want the coresponding numseats value to be set to 0. Like so:

```
 ---------------------------------
| bookingID | numseats | status |
---------------------------------
| 1         | 0        | C      |
```

Implying that the booking has been cancelled and the seats unallocated.

So I decided that a trigger function was my best bet. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION removeSeats()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    UPDATE flightbooking
    set NEW.numseats = 0;
    return NEW;

END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


--Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER removeseats
AFTER UPDATE 
on flightbooking
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.status = 'C' )
EXECUTE PROCEDURE removeSeats();
```

Now initially the lines

```
set NEW.numseats = 0;
```

was

```
set numseats = 0;
```

This executed but set ALL the fields of numseats to 0 instead of ''THIS'' field. Which is why I decided I needed to use NEW. However that throws the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "new" of relation "flightbooking" does not exist
LINE 2:  set NEW.numseats = 0
```

This is the query I am using to test the trigger function

```
update flightbooking
set status = 'C'
where bookingid = 1
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use a `before` trigger and simply assign the value: `NEW.numseats := 0;` no `update` needed. See the manual for examples. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for an UPDATE at all. In a before trigger you can simply assign the value you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION removeSeats()
   RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    NEW.numseats := 0;
    return NEW;

END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Changing the `NEW` record directly is much more efficient then running a second update for each row that was updated.

In order for this to  work, you have to define your trigger as a `BEFORE` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER removeseats
BEFORE UPDATE 
on flightbooking
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.status = 'C' )
EXECUTE PROCEDURE removeSeats();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is wrong and there is no where clause in your update query.

Try it in this way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION removeSeats()
 RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;

UPDATE flightbooking
set numseats = 0 WHERE bookingid = NEW.bookingid;
return NEW;

END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```